# Webdriver returns error for textarea.sendKeys(text)

Tags: selenium, textarea, webdriver, sendkeys, selenium-webdriver

I am using Webdriver 2.25.0 and Firefox 14

I have the following textarea:

```
<textarea id="source-text" placeholder="Start typing your text" style="resize: none; overflow: hidden;"></textarea>
```

I am identifying this text area in my HomePage object like this:

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "div.myclass textarea")
public WebElement columnLeftTextarea;
```

What i want to do is simply type some text inside this textarea, by using the following code

```
homePage.columnLeftTextarea.sendKeys("some text");
```

This is returning the following error:

```
Type mismatch Can't assign non-array value to an array
```

The textarea is correctly defined as when i run

```
 homePage.columnLeftTextarea.getAttribute("placeholder")
```

i get the correct text

I even tried to do start the browser by setting the capabilities to tnable native events:

```
FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile(new File(generalPropertiesTestObject.getFirefox_profile_template_location()));
        ffProfile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
        FirefoxDriver ffd = new FirefoxDriver(ffProfile);
        capabilities = ffd.getCapabilities();
```

But still i am getting the same error. Does anyone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try firstly focusing into textarea. I did it using the following code:

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("source-text")).clear();
 driver.findElement(By.id("source-text")).sendKeys("some text");
```

and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: thanks Arek. That was the problem, i missed clearing the textarea first

Comment: No problem. Please also take a look at Yury's post. You really should consider changing your locators to IDs as they are much faster and do not change so often.

Answer (score 0):

You need change this code:

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "div.myclass textarea")
public WebElement columnLeftTextarea;
```

on this:

```
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "source-text") 
public WebElement columnLeftTextarea;
```

Firstly, it works more faster, because search by ID works more faster than search by CSS.
Secondly, ID changes is not so much time as CSS.

Comment: this response adds nothing to the question